# How to create JavaScript like simple objects in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript, what's the best way to create simple objects like this one in JavaScript:

```
var newObj = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop2: 1,
    prop3: {}
}
```

Comment: That's not valid Javascript syntax

Comment: you're right. my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax is valid, both in Javascript and Typescript, and represents the most idiomatic way to define a new object literal.

```
var newObj = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop2: 1,
    prop3: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any valid Javascript is also valid Typescript, so you can write any Javascript object, as in Robby's answer! However, you might want to create a TypeScript class in order to define an object: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

For example, from the TypeScript docs:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

Then, you can construct an object of this class:

```
let g = new Greeter("hi");
```